# Android timestamp inconsistencies

Tags: android, galaxy, android-sensors

I'm running an NDK app pulling sensor data from the gyroscope, accelerometer, and magnometer. On a Galaxy S3 things are working as expected, but on the S4 Android is reporting inconsistent event timestamps (in the event.timestamp field). The gyroscope and accelerometer are using system uptime but the magnometer is using epoch time.

Has anyone else seen this, with an S4 or other phone? I did just recently upgrade the S4 to using Android 4.3 and I believe (but not 100% certain) this did not happen before. Also, does anyone know the proper forum for reporting bugs like these to Samsung?

Comment: I'm using HTC ONE MAX v:5.0 . I also struggle with inconsistnet interal/tick of data recieved from ACC_LINEAR. Sometimes it speed up sometimes it slow down. I make me crazy, bacause I'm using this sensor go recognize hand movements and this requires that the sequence of values should have the same intervals.. ;( . Answering on your question. I don't know why it happens. I thought that is normal, but it seems it doesen't, because you said on your Galaxy S3 timestamp is equal.